# how to turn off Heroku SQL logs from postgres

Tags: postgresql, logging, heroku, heroku-postgres

I'm running an application on Heroku that uses postgres.

All of my SQL statements are coming through in my logs; I'd like to turn this off.

They look like this:

```
Dec 03 05:41:36 ti-core app/postgres:  [1566-2] #011FROM alias  
Dec 03 05:41:36 ti-core app/postgres:  [1566-3] #011WHERE alias.nid = E'10.5334/sta.at' AND alias.namespace = E'doi'  
Dec 03 05:41:36 ti-core app/postgres:  [1566-4] #011 LIMIT 1
```

I can't figure out where I've set this level of heroku postgres debugging and where to turn it down a notch.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Presumably it comes from `log_statement` being set to `all`.

To reset it:

- for the entire cluster: comment `log_statement` in postgresql.conf or set it to `'none'`
- for the database: `ALTER DATABASE foo SET log_statement=default;`
- for a user: `ALTER USER foo SET log_statement=default;`

If that doesn't help, check `log_min_duration_statement`.

Relevant documentation chapter: [Error Reporting and Logging](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html).

Comment: Thanks Daniel.  This is helpful, but I don't have permission to set log_statement on my Heroku-hosted postgres, it would appear:  
ERROR: ERROR: permission denied to set parameter "log_statement".  So maybe I need to change a setting in Heroku somewhere?

Comment: @HeatherPiwowar, please, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39882730/1421194). I.e. since 3 years another user has same problem, and I don't have solution for it. Did you get something new since then?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is probably not the right answer but I solved partially the problem with the following command (at least when I am reading logs in real time):

`heroku logs --tail | grep -v 'Executing'`

where the `-v` parameter inverts the grep search, so that only other log messages are shown (assuming they don't have the text 'Executing' in their content).

I hope this helps.